# eXist-DB configure security for REST / PUT requests

Tags: exist-db

I have a simple contact form on my website which successfully issues a `HTTP PUT` to my eXist-db.

Each `PUT` creates a unique XML document like so:
    `http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr/exist/rest/db/apps/deheresi/comm/some_unique_name.xml`

When it does so, the server demands a password.

What are the best practices for configuring `HTTP PUT` for public write, but not read/edit?

Is this simply a matter of creating a unique user / password just for this REST activity that allows only write access to this collection?

Are there other considerations?

Is there a specific, recommended eXist-db approach to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a few options:

1. Make use of the Collection permissions, e.g. owner/group/mode/acl and use a user or group, which is authenticated in the HTTP PUT to control who can write to the Collection.

   The mode `rwx` for a Collection:

   1. `r` (read) enables a user/group to list the contents of the Collection
   2. `w` (write) enables a user/group to write to the Collection; NOTE that this 
      includes deleting documents!
   3. `x` (execute) enables a user/group to open the Collection, without 'x' neither `r` or `w` will be permitted.

   However, as Collections are exposed over the HTTP REST API unless you disable the REST API, you likely don't want to give a public user `w` access to your Collection. As they could then just HTTP DELETE document(s) in the Collection.
2. Instead you likely want a public user which has `s` (set-uid + execute) access on an XQuery Main Module exposed via the REST API or a RESTXQ end-point. This main-module when accessed via HTTP PUT would then assume an effective user id, and write to the Collection. The advantags of HTTP PUT'ing to an XQuery Main Module rather than to a Collection:

   1. that you can use the XQuery Main Module to ignore HTTP DELETE/POST/GET etc, which prevents the user from directly modifying the Collection.
   2. You don't need to share the credentials of your privileged user outside of eXist-db.
   3. The XQuery Main Module becomes task specific and so has a much smaller attack service and acts as a limited point of access control.

   In your XQuery Main Module you will also want to likely set specific permission on the document(s) that you are creating.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful summary. If I am doing this as a main module do I need to provide a response? Should I use `response:set-status-code()` for this?

Comment: After working through this I have the user submit XML which hits a main module that processes it after checking the HTTP type for POST and rejecting the other types. I return `response:set-status-code()` for the various results and problems. Using PUT actually has the effect of replacing the code in the .xqm with the XML! POST allows the module to ingest the manipulate the XML received in the HTTP data.